# Audio Session Interruption Listener not called

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording, audiosession

AudioSessionCategory is set to PlayAndRecord.
I have an interruption listener and in the first line of it:

```
printf("hello\n");
```

My app can record wav, caf and mp4.
When my app is recording in wav format and an interruption arrives I can see "hello" in my Xcode and my app handles it correctly. But when it is recording in caf or mp4 format and an interruption arrives there's no "hello" in Xcode and my app crashes after interruption ends.
Why my interruption callback is not called?

**EDIT :**
Apple's sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222
it's interruption listener was not called during converting to aac!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION RATHER A WORKAROUND :
```

I have found that the problem occurs when only recording in kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC format.
But you can change that to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD and it works perfectly.
i still appreciate any answer to my question .